# page not redirecting in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hi I am doing small login application using `servlet`, my response am redirecting a another `jsp` but its getting redirected, Below is my code is there

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from sahi_users where username = ? and password = ?");
        ps.setString(1, request.getParameter("userName"));
        ps.setString(2, request.getParameter("pass"));
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();   
        while (rs.next()) {
            check = true;
        }           
        if(check){
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("user", request.getParameter("userName"));
            //setting session to expiry in 30 mins
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30*60);
            Cookie userName = new Cookie("user", request.getParameter("userName"));
            userName.setMaxAge(30*60);
            response.addCookie(userName);
            response.sendRedirect("./Login.jsp");
        }else{
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp");
            PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
            //out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
                rd.include(request, response);              
            }
```

Thanks in advance,
Suganth.A

Answer (score 0):

In if condition use `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/Login.jsp");`

In else condition you are not forwarding RequestDispatcher.

use below code in else method

```
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: if i given exact username and password also its not geting redirected?

Comment: when you give correct username and password. can you see change in url?

Comment: Hi Gautam,No url is not getting changed

Comment: @Suganth did you tried with change in if condition as I mentioned

Comment: yes i have changed and tested its not redirecting, on the responce in js i put an alert, that alert displaying the jsp page waht i need to redirect.   $.post("./login",
     {
      userName:username,
      pass:passwword
     },
     function(data,status){
      alert(data);
     });

Comment: What is the servlet that you want to redirect to?

Comment: @hubert not going to redirecting a servlet am redirecting to a jsp page name Login.jsp